# Apache - Read Cookie value and set RequestHeader

Tags: linux, apache, cookies

I need to add a RequestHeader value in Apache with information that I got from a cookie. To understand what I mean exactly, I will make an Example:

The cookie informations looks like this:

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=E9CE2C1AC104EEDD6EF40736568BED49; LoginID=1479415168; Username_ID=alfonso
```

Now I need to add in apache the `RequestHeader` like this

```
RequestHeader add X-FILTER-Username "Username_ID"
```

I haven´t find any possibility to read cookie value `Username_ID` and set this as a variable in apache vhost configuration.

May somebody have an idea?